# How can I train my cat not to scratch furniture?

Tags: cats, scratching

How could I train my cat not to scratch everything while I need to go to school and my mother to work? I want educational advices that i could learn her when she is little. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your best option is to work *with* your cat's instincts, rather than against them. Cats have an instinct to scratch so you need to provide suitable objects for them to scratch on that are more attractive than your furniture. Buy (or make) several scratching posts, bait them with catnip, and place them around the house. Cats like to scratch when they wake up, so put scratching posts near favourite sleeping spots. Another good place is right next to any place your cat has a tendency to scratch (like the arm of a sofa).

Reward your kitten (with treats or praise) for using the scratching posts, and she will build good associations with sratching there. She will learn to prefer scratching on the surfaces you provide instead of your furniture.

Comment: In addition, if the cat just has some favourite scratching-spot:give in, and put a scratching-board there.

Comment: When i play with my cat, i usually do it around the scratching posts so that he learns this is the place he can go wild on.

Comment: I've also found it helpful to purposely direct my cats toward the desired scratch surfaces by gently taking both their paws and setting them on the surface (sometimes redirecting from the furniture). Both quickly grasp that the new surface is for scratching, and often much more fun to scratch at than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You need your cat to know that it is wrong. Pull it away when it is doing it, or give it a little lecture. But don't do anything mean, it will just be scared of you. Buy something for it to scratch like a special cat carpet or scratching post, so it can scratch that. You may use a spray that keeps away your cat. Reward you cat when it scratches on the scratching post. As I said the best way it to teach it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double-sided tape where you don’t want your cat to scratch. I've researched that cat’s don’t like to step on or touch sticky surfaces, so this should act as a great deterrent and guard against your cat’s usual scratching routine.

Answer (score 0):

**How to train your cat to scratch where you want:**

1) Make a scratching post available, at least one that is available at all times for the cat.

2) Establish a correction word. I use the local variant of "No!" for my cat. So every time he does something I want him to stop, I just say "No!", sometimes quite forcefully. He does get the message.

3) Every time your cat starts to scratch where you don't want to, you say your correction word, take the cat and put their claws to the scratching post you want them to use. Do not get angry, or violent. Just show your cat where you want it to scratch.

4) Make the old scratching points less enjoying to use. Dubble sided tape, strange and unpleasant smells. Google cat anti scratching stuff.